# What is the best way to enumerate bitmask Flags contained within a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, bitmask

I'm working with an old (>15 years) system that stored attributes using char[] arrays, where if the index had an "X", that attribute was activated. I've done this much to convert it:

```
...

[Flags]
public enum PDMObjectFlags {
    None    = 0,     // 000000
    OptionA = 1,     // 000001
    OptionB = 2,     // 000010
    OptionC = 4,     // 000100
    OptionD = 8,     // 001000
    OptionE = 16,    // 010000
    OptionF = 32     // 100000
}

...

string userOptionsStr = "   XXX";           // "   XXX"
string userOptionsBin = userOptions
                       .Replace('X', '1')
                       .Replace(' ', '0');  // "000111"
int userOptionsInt = 
    Convert.ToInt32(userOptionsBin, 2);     // 7
```

How do I end up with something that will allow me to display all of a particular user's attributes? Something like this:

```
foreach (var x in userOptionsList){
    Console.Write("John's account has " + x);
}

// Output:
// 
// John's account has OptionA
// John's account has OptionB
// John's account has OptionC
```

Sorry if the example is dumb, I just typed it out here. It will eventually be passed with a model into a Razor View and iterated on the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have this as an integer, you can convert back to the enum and use `ToString()` to pull out the list of names.

Given enum defined as (which compiles):

```
[Flags]
public enum PDMObjectFlags {
    None     = 0,    // 000000
    A = 1,    // 000001
    B = 2,    // 000010
    C = 4,    // 000100
    D = 8,    // 001000
    E = 16,   // 010000
    F = 32    // 100000
}
```

You can extend your code with:

```
PDMObjectFlags flags = (PDMObjectFlags)userOptionsInt;  
var names = flags.ToString().Split(new[] {',',' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach(var name in names)
    Console.WriteLine("John\'s account has Option {0}", name);
```

This will print the output you specified, ie:

> John's account has Option A
>
> John's account has Option B
>
> John's account has Option C

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I knew I was frustratingly close. :) I'd + if I had the rep. I'll accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @ReedCopsey [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that " the return value is a string containing a **delimiter-separated** list of the names of the constants". Is it safe to use `,`?

Comment: @AlexD The delimiter used is a comma, though.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Regardless of regional settings or whatsoever, correct?

Comment: @AlexD Yes, I believe that it always uses comma - but I'd verify if required.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Sorry, I had to do it myself before asking. Just looked at http://referencesource.microsoft.com. They seem to use `private const String enumSeperator = ", ";` (Still, strictly speaking, it does not guarantee that the separator is going to be the same always.) Thanks anyway!